# Copy what I write to seperate worksheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to type into any cell in the worksheet and have it automatically copy to the second worksheet as I type. I know how I can copy from the current cell to another but I do not know how to do this live. I want to do this in VBA I know I can select both worksheets and just type but I want to do this in VBA.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Copy
irow = ActiveCell.Row
icol = ActiveCell.Column

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(irow, icol).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

End Sub

Comment: you should look into the [Worksheet.Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event. "[It] occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link."

Comment: I don't think you've really thought this through. Excel does not support live editing in two worksheets at the same time, and running a macro on every keystroke to manually update the second sheet is going to make it pretty much impossible to use, especially by someone who is good at data entry.

Comment: @KenWhite good point, maybe it should operate based on a save or even a close event instead?

Comment: Maybe set cells from another sheet equal to your current sheet, or use INDIRECT, to copy data over - then use a macro to copy paste values to remove the formulas? It doesn't sound like excel can handle your question's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this short event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you for this but where is it actually pasting? I did try run it and followed the directions you listed but it did not work.

Comment: @James into `Sheet2`, change the name of the sheet in the code if you have another worksheet in mind

Comment: @James  It should go in the same address-space.  If you type something in *Sheet1* cell **B9** it should get copied to *Sheet2* cell **B9**

Comment: @James  Remember this code is installed in a special place, the worksheet code area.  See my instructions

Comment: Thank you for some reason had to restart the worksheet.

Comment: @James  Thanks for the feedback